# Getting the error "Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory"

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, babeljs, vue-cli

Receiving this error message `Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory` when i run my project `npm run dev or npm run build`

Would really appreciate some help, been trying to solve this for two days.

```
Error Log

ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Couldn't find preset "env" relative to directory "/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website"
    at /Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
    at new File (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/Users/marvinbenno/Documents/Code projects/the-ultimate-website/the-ultimate-website-sneaekpeak/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:50:20)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js main[2]"
```

```
./webpack.config.js

var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

```
./package.json

{
  "name": "the-ultimate-website",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Marvin <marvinkristusbenno@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.14",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.11",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

#### Project Code

https://github.com/Marre1020/the-ultimate-website-sneakpeak

Comment: could you share github link to this project? need to check your code

Comment: @divine here is my github and the repositorylink https://github.com/Marre1020/the-ultimate-website-sneakpeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't checkin `node_modules/` directory into git respository. Make sure you use `.gitignore` properly.

All of your errors are occuring during build time

#### Try below steps to fix the error occuring during build time

- Download your project from your gitrepo and place it into a newfolder
- Delete `node_modules` directory
- Install all the modules using `npm install`
- In your `package.json` you've included `cross-env` script to start your project.
  Do not install it globally. You have to install this library local to the project.
  When you deploy your project to any server you need this `cross-env` to start your project. Install `cross-env` package as a prod dependency.
  `npm install --save cross-env`
- You have included `vue-style-loader` in your `webpack.config.js`. But you haven't installed this loader. Install `vue-style-loader` to allow webpack to parse the styles coded inside your `.vue` files
  `npm install --save-dev vue-style-loader`
- The `vue-loader` which you use currently `"vue-loader": "^15.7.0"` requires plugin to be configured in `webpack.config.js`. Include `VueLoaderPlugin` after `devtool configuration` as shown below.

```
./webpack.config.js

...
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
   ...
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  plugins : [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}
```

- Run your project in development mode `npm run dev` to view the output in browser.Chrome browser is preferred. i've ignored the warning messages produced by your code in the node console, you have to takecare of it.

#### Uglify plugin causes few problems while building the project for production

`npm run build`

i suggest you to remove uglifyjs related configuration from your `webpack.config.js` and test your code in production mode. You can proceed with researching more on how to fix the problem with uglifyjs plugin or post a new question.

#### Webpack configuration without uglifyjs plugin

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  plugins : [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```